# PHP error oci_bind_by_name(): Invalid variable used for bind

Tags: php, rss

I have a PHP file which will extract data from an RSS feed and insert it into a database. Usually I wrap each field with a custom function to replace quotes but no longer need it (because of a change in requirements). For some reason when I use the logic below I get an error "error oci_bind_by_name(): Invalid variable used for bind" but if I wrap each field in the custom function like this:

```
$guid = customfunction($item->guid);
```

it works, why?

Thank you

```
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {




   print '<a href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a><br />';

    $guid = $item->guid;
    $title = $item->title;
    $link = $item->link;
    $pubDate = $item->pubDate;
    $description = $item->description;
    $content = $item->content;

    $stid = oci_parse($spConn,"INSERT INTO table123
                (sku, title, link, pubDate, field1, field2)
                VALUES(:guid_bv, :title_bv, :link_bv, :pubDate_bv, :description_bv, :content_bv)");


                oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":guid_bv", $guid);
                oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":title_bv", $title);
                oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":link_bv", $link);
                oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":pubDate_bv", $pubDate);
                oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":description_bv", $description);
                oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":content_bv", $content);

                oci_execute($stid);
```

Comment: are any of those values null?

Comment: Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php example 3

Comment: @Dimi none of them are null for sure.

Comment: @u_mulder not sure how this helps?

Comment: i know that this is kind of weird, but try to wrap all of the values that you are binding in strval like  strval($guid) in your bind command and see if that works... I had to do it once a while ago, not sure why, but it fixed my issue at the time

Comment: @Dimi thank you!! That did it! I never knew about strval(). How can I give you credit for answering and fixing my issue?

Comment: Did you read a comment in example3?

Comment: My educated guess is that `$rss` is an instance of `SimpleXML`. As such, all other variables are `SimpleXML` as well thus `oci_bind_by_name()` gets terribly confused.

Answer (score 0):

By default, oci_bind_by_name() requires only 3 parameters, and treats all variables that you bind as characters. It works fine for most cases however, but if you are try to add a float, binary data or integers it might scream at you and complain about invalid variable used. To fix this either you need to either give oci_bind_by_name another set of  parameters, ex:

```
  if(is_numeric($v2)){ 
    oci_bind_by_name($stmth, $bvar, $v2,  8, OCI_B_INT); 
  }else{ 
    $v2 = (string) $v2; 
    oci_bind_by_name($stmth, $bvar, $v2, -1, SQLT_CHR); 
  }
```

or simply wrap your variable in strval() like this

```
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":description_bv", strval($description));
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":content_bv", strval($content));
```

While I strongly advise creating/using a custom class that will handle all variable binds for you, using strval() with your variables should eliminate all "Invalid variable used for bind" errors when passing integers, doubles or other formats.